# For what reasons could ActionMailer not find a template in production, despite being able to do so locally?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, debugging, actionmailer

I'm receiving this error only in production and it's driving me nuts.

`ActionView::MissingTemplateapp/mailers/project_mailer.rb:41
Missing template project_mailer/project_introduction with "mailer". Searched in: * "project_mailer"`

Line 41 is the line beginning with `mail(`

**app/mailers/project_mailer.rb**

```
def project_introduction(project_introduction_id)
  @project_introduction = ProjectIntroduction.find(project_introduction_id)

  mail(
    to: @project_introduction.project.user.email,
    cc: [@project_introduction.user.email, @project_introduction.user.company.cc],
      subject: "Introduction to Your New Match, #{@project_introduction.user.company.name} for Project ##{@project_introduction.project_id}"
  )
end
```

I've even SSH'd into production and found that the view exists there.

What else can I look into?

Comment: can you post your code?

Comment: @zahid - Updated the original post.

Comment: @thaleshcv - Updated the original post

Comment: Please tell us name of your mailer template is it project_introduction.html.erb?

Comment: also is this the complete code or you are doing any attachments as well?

Comment: You are correct about the name of the mailer. It's found in `app/views/project_mailer/project_introduction.html.erb`

Comment: No attachments @zahid

Comment: Can you try to pass template name in mail function like   mail(
    to: @project_introduction.project.user.email,
      subject: "123", template_name: 'project_introduction'
  )

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89936/discussion-between-zahid-and-dylan-richards).